# How to implement gestures in cocos2d for a specific scene

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, gesture, swipe, scene

I'm making a card game using cocos2d for iOS and the user can simply swipe the card upward to choose his card, which means he doesn't need to swipe anywhere else in the game. This might be a really dumb question, but even after scouring the Internet for the past two days, I couldn't find anything specific to implement Gesture recognition (namely, swiping upward) in one scene alone and not the entire app. I read the documentation for UISwipeGestureRecognizer documentation by Apple, numerous blogs and few other video tutorials. All I could find was implementing it in an app with a single scene. A little nudge in the right direction would be terrific. I really will appreciate it if you provide me with some sort of sample code as well. I've understood the concept of the methods CCTouchesBegan, etc. But I'm still blind as to how to implement swiping one of the two sprites(cards) in the PlayerScene (scene where players choose cards) alone.

Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: UISwipeGestureRecognizer will not work, as you are using cocos2d. You will need to create your own gesture recognizer code.

Comment: That's sad. Could you please give me some sort of example code from where I can start working? I just have this horrible starting trouble cocos2d and obj C. I'm new to this. I read about manipulating AppDelegate.m applicationDidFinishLoading method but I'm still blind. Please help

Comment: Check out this topic here on the cocos2d forums: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8929 I haven't used it however

Comment: @Richard: There's no reason why UISwipeGestureRecognizer shouldn't work because of cocos2d. It does work, all of the gesture recognizers work.

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as adding a UIGestureRecognizer at some point in time, then removing that gesture recognizer when you no longer need it. In your case that could be in the -(void) cleanup method of your scene. There's no reason why gesture recognizers need to be global.

You should check out [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) (based on cocos2d), for which I created a [super-easy wrapper for gesture recognizers](http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKDOC/KKInput+Gestures). With that all you need to do is to set the [corresponding "enabled" flag](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Kobold2D/html/interface_k_k_input.html#a8e25606dc58ed28c5ebeaf0128094bcf) to YES and later to NO to start and stop gesture recognizers.

Comment: Actually, it is recommended to add / remove touch events on the `-onEnter` and `-onExit` methods.

Comment: Who does recommend that where? The only reason I can think of is that onEnter will only be called after any transition has finished, so adding the touch events there avoids receiving touch events during a transition.

Comment: It is recommended in the cocos2d beginners guide, here http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips:touchdelegates

Comment: Ah yes. I love the cocos2d documentation. Usually doesn't tell you why you should favor doing one thing over another, just that it's "better" or "recommended". I suppose it's like I suspected, to avoid receiving touches during a transition. I can't imagine anything else.